# Is there a way to navigate around an image by clicking and dragging in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When zoomed in on an image in VSCode's image viewer window, I want to be able to navigate around the image by clicking and dragging, instead of scrolling/using the scroll bars.

The only navigation cursors that I'm able to get in VSCode's image viewer window are a Zoom-In cursor (default) and a Zoom-Out cursor (while holding option on Mac).

Comment: create a VSC feature request if not obvious UI does the trick, or a VSC doc feature request

Answer (score 0):

You can press the scroll wheel.

Open the image with another software.